# cURL security insert into database

Tags: php

I have a sign up form

```
post--> to data_checking --post--> insert_db page
```

Inside my `data_checking` page, I will check everything, the length, SQL injection etc.

However, if user know my `$_POST['']`, they can skip data_checking page and insert their data into db. For example, if a hacker knows my `$_POST['email']` they can just send this data by cURL.

Any suggestion how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just reuse the checking functions before inserting the data into DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always integrate the data checking into the database insert php (I don't see why they aren't combined in the first place), or if you just can't do that you can send a very complex key as some post to confirm that the script is sending the data.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the interstitial HTTP requests between the data checking and data inserting scripts, or call the functions that perform the data checking in the data inserting script.